# What is the meaning of pre-and post composing?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

In my linear algebra class my professor kept on using the words, precompose, and postcompose. Can someone verify if it is the case that:

Pre-composing $A$ with $B$ means $A \circ B$

and

Post-composing $A$ with $B$ means $B \circ A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, exactly backwards, because the second operation goes on the left with functional notation. If you postcompose $A$ with $B$, that means you compose $A$ "after" or second. So $AB$. Precompose $A$ to get $BA$. $ABv$ means take a vector $v$, do operator $B$ to it, then afterwards do operation $A$ to the resulting vector.

Comment: Alternatively "postcompose $A$ with $B$" could mean that you take $A$ and modify it by putting $B$ _after_ it, yielding $B\circ A$. It's ambiguous -- not based on what "pre" or "post" mean, but on how they relate to the rest of the sentence.

Comment: I think you got it wrong and OP got it right. The thing that is post-composed with comes after, i.e. on the left. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3889401/what-are-post-composition-and-pre-composition-in-category-theory)

Answer (score 2):

I would say those wordings are ambiguous, because they include both of the maps, and there's nothing to make it clear *which* of them the "pre" or "post" speaks about. The fact that one of them takes a "with" doesn't really help.

My best advice would be to write "$A\circ B$" in symbols when there is any danger of misunderstanding. If you have to understand something someone else has written, you're unfortunately left to figure out what makes most sense in context.

A coarse rule of thumb would be that if $A$ is either something big and complex, or an *arbitrary* map you know nothing specific about, and $B$ is something simple which merely *modifies* the behavior of $A$, then "pre-compose" means to form $A\circ B$ and "post-compose" means $B\circ A$ -- no matter which is grammatically a direct object and which has a preposition.