# What are post-composition and pre-composition in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

What are post-composition and pre-composition of morphisms in category theory?

The context of my question is to understand Lemma 1.2.3 in Riehl's book.

> Lemma 1.2.3. The following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $f: x \rightarrow y$ is an isomorphism in $C$.
>
> (ii) For all objects $c \in C$, post-composition with $f$ defines a bijection $$f_{\ast} : C(c, x) \rightarrow C(c, y).$$
>
> (iii) For all objects $c \in C$, pre-composition with $f$ defines a bijection $$f^{\ast} : C(y, c) \rightarrow C(x, c).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In either case, it's about composing morphisms with $f$.

(ii) Take an element of $C(c,x)$, which is to say, a morphism $g:c\to x$. Then compose this with $f$ to get $$f\circ g:c\to y$$which is an element of $C(c,y)$. In this case, we first follow $g$ from $c$ to $x$, then *afterwards* we follow $f$ from $x$ to $y$. This means we are *post-composing* with $f$.

(iii) Take an element of $C(y, c)$, which is to say, a morphism $h:y\to c$. Then compose this with $f$ to get $$h\circ f:x\to c$$which is an element of $C(x,c)$. In this case, we *first* follow $f$ from $x$ to $y$, then afterwards we follow $h$ from $y$ to $c$. This means we are *pre-composing* with $f$.

Note that in $f\circ g$, we say $f$ is post-composed, even though we write $f$ in front of $g$. This might seem strange, but it is a natural result of our convention of writing functions to the left of their argument (we say $f(x)$ rather than $(x)f$).

Comment: Thanks. And I suppose in the lemma, she means with bijection an isomorphism?

Comment: No, I think they mean bijection when they say bijection.

Comment: Hmm. But what does bijection mean in this context? Since post-composition and pre-composition are morphisms in a category. And we are not assuming concrete categories, so the morphisms do not necessarily have to be maps between sets.

Comment: @rising_sea But $C(x,c)$ and the three others are sets (if $C$ is locally small) or classes, and bijections in those cases are well-defined notions.

Comment: Yes sure. But how do you know that the category is locally small? It's not mentioned as a hypothesis in the lemma.

Comment: @rising_sea as Arthur said, the notion of bijection between classes is not problematic.